# Is it ok for ID numbers (database) to have decimal points?

Tags: sql, json, database, primary-key

I have a JSON file where the ID numbers are decimal numbers. And they don't run in any specific order - like 58.0, 792.0, and so on. But the number in this decimal (tenths position) is always 0 (it appears).

So as this could be a random sample of data from a bigger data set, I am reluctant to set new ID numbers at the same time that I create a new table in PostgreSQL to put this data into.

What is the best way to deal with these decimal numbers - is there a way to just get rid of the decimal point, or should I start at 1 when I create a fresh table to load the JSON data into?

Comment: This is something you should ask whoever is providing the JSON - it might be an actual decimal or might be an int that is just serialized as a decimal - In any case, the fact that the numbers are an what seems to be a random order could lead to fragmentation of the index - I don't know about postgreSQL but in SQL Server you can declare a primary key as non-clustered and have another index be your clustered index - so this is something to be considered, by someone that a) knows more than me about postgresql and b) knows the specific needs of your system and the data you are dealing with.

Comment: Be clear on what this data *is* and *represents*. Just because something is composed of digits (and here, a `.`), that doesn't necessarily mean it should be treated as a number *at all*. E.g. a telephone number, despite being all digits, is almost always more sensibly stored as a string. Similarly, software version numbers *aren't* decimal numbers.

Comment: I don't know what it represents. It is just listed under "ID" number so it seems to be a primary key. The records contain different pieces of info in relation to a vehicle.

Comment: Ask the JSON provider if the decimal pont is intended or a mere mistake. They may tell you these are decimal numbers, then store them as such. Or they may fix their generator and provide you with integers instead, then store integers. Or they may tell you, it's just as string (as Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out) and you may also get IDs like `44.X` for instance, then store strings. Without asking them you would have to store strings in order to be on the save side.

Comment: Floating point numbers are a bad idea for an ID, as matching ("find something with ID 13.1") may be inexact. See any number of "is floating point broken" questions. But for a string ID it is no problem (but note that 13.1 and 13.10 are then different).

Comment: Looks like it's a string ID. e.g. "ID":"976.0" is how it appears in the JSON.

Comment: If **all** of those numbers have `.0` then I would assume that whatever system is generating those JSON values it formats the integer values incorrectly (appending `.0`)  but in reality those values are integers, not decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Let sit back and discuss the principle, we all know that the ID (identity / identifier) column is used to determine the table row among others. Not like the primary column(s), it is more likely to be set by the database engine when data row is inserted into the table.

The best way is to map the ID field from JSON to a column called as `original_ID`, and enable auto generated `ID` for your data.

For example, your table schema looks like

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
 ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 . . .
 original_ID DECIMAL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

With this design, you may have a future proof for changes to some extends.

Comment: I am thinking to use Pentaho (ETL tool).

Comment: The question is whether you can / want to modify the target table (schema) or not?. My suggestion was based on the assumption that you can ( and want). If not, then you can update your question and we can look into how to solve it

Comment: I wish I were knowledgeable enough to say. For now I am trying to do it without the use of the ETL tool. I want to dump the data as is for now into postgresql and then work off that as the new source data table.